# Run a method in loop in 3 seconds interval on web MVC .net app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to run a method periodically in 3 second in my MVC .net app. Which makes an http get request to another server and fetch data. 
I tried this with Hangfire tool but it allow minimum 1 minute duration.
I also tried to run a thread on app_start in global.asax with while(true) loop. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private const int minutes = 3;
private static bool active = true;

public static void FetchData()
{
    // Send your requests using HttpWebRequest / WebClient
}

public static async Task BeginTimer()
{
    while (active)
    {
        await Task.Delay(minutes * 1000);
        FetchData();
    }
}

public static void StopTimer()
{
    active = false;
}
```

When `BeginTimer()` is triggered, it will loop infinitely until `StopTimer()` is called which will exit out of the `while` loop after the next data collection.

Comment: Hi Nathangard, thanks for your answer. I accept  this logic  which will work fine for me, but how to run this continuously independent of session. I fire BeginTimer() method from controller but it stopped after few minutes. May be due to session out. So is there another way to achieve this? I wanted to run this for lifetime. Same as Hangfire do with RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate() method

Answer (score 0):

Have similar problem, decided to use "Scheduler" on Microsoft Azure. Another option, write console app with `while(true)` cycle which will run requests continuously.

EDIT: It can be pricy to use Scheduler every 3 seconds.